# make xargs accept multiline string as single parameter

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, xargs

```
git log --format=%B -n 1 HEAD | xargs -I{} npx ts-node --esm ./foobar.ts {}
```

I have this line of code, which has the purpose of using git to pass the latest commit-message to a script which will look for deployment tags within the message.

For commit messages with more than one line, xargs is calling foobar.ts multiple times with each line of the commit message as the input though, instead of passing the whole message as one single parameter. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `-0` to tell `xargs` that the arguments to pass to the command are to be found NUL-delimited on its input, and since a commit log can't contain a NUL character, that would pass the whole input (including the line delimiter of the last line) to the command as one argument:

```
git log --format=%B -n 1 HEAD |
  xargs -r0 npx ts-node --esm ./foobar.ts
```

Beware though that while all current `xargs` implementations don't ignore that non-delimited record, [that's a potentially dangerous thing for them to do in the general case](https://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=243#c6093), and POSIX which will specify `-r` and `-0` in the next version of the standard [recommends (though does not mandate) ignoring it](https://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=243#c6110):

> If the standard input is not empty and does not end with a null byte, `xargs` should ignore the trailing non-null bytes (as this can signal incomplete data) but may use them as the last argument passed to utility.

So relying on that may not be future-proof. You could add a NUL with `(git...; printf '\0') | xargs -r0...` but as it happens, `git log` supports a `-z` option to delimit commits with NULs, so that would make it future-proof:

```
git log --format=%B -zn 1 HEAD |
  xargs -r0 npx ts-node --esm ./foobar.ts
```

And would even allow you to send more than one commit across.

Alternatively, you could use your shell's command substitution:

```
npx ts-node --esm ./foobar.ts "$(git log --format=%B -n 1 HEAD)"
```

Command substitution strips all trailing newline characters, including the line delimiter of the last non-empty line and all following empty lines after that if any, which here is likely desirable.

In any case, you can't use `xargs`' `-I` here without using either `-0` or `-d` as with it, `xargs` still does quote processing in its input and would choke on commit logs that contain apostrophes for instance or mangle anything that contains quotes or backslashes.